# cant order by pending status

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to get the results of all the rows with a pending status and after that display the rest that dont have pending . I cant get the syntax right to order the data this way . I want all the pending value rows and then all the other non-pending rows.

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
               // 'conditions' => array('request_status' => 'pending') , 
              'order' => array('request_status' => 'pending','request_date'=> 'desc'),   
    'limit' => 5  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'request_status' => 'pending'` should be either `'request_status' => 'asc'` or `'request_status' => 'desc'` depending on preference. It doesn't belong in the order conditions as you have specified as its part of a WHERE clause and not an ORDER BY

EDIT:

IF its a standard display that you're looking to render, then use the model rather than pagination settings. I had difficulty with them before. So in the model you would define an order variable

```
 public $order = array("request_status" => "ASC");
```

or

```
public $order = array("request_status" => "DESC");
```

In the controller for a view, it would be a case of calling the standard

```
$this->set('mydata' , $this->Paginator->paginate);
```

Comment: This doesnt work. I get the pending conditions only. I want the pending rows first and then the rest after this which are not pending. $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                'conditions' => array('request_status' => 'pending') , 
              'order' => array('request_status' => 'desc'),   
             'limit' => 5  );

Comment: sorry i am not getting this to work. There must be a simple way to just display all the pending results and after that display all the non-pending results

Comment: I also got t to work by adding a new field with a request number, that made it easy to sort

Answer (score 0):

You can sort on multiple columns, and you can sort different columns in different directions. For example, to sort by type of request_date in descending order, then by request_status within request_type in descending order ('youngest' request_date first), use the following query:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM pet
    -> ORDER BY request_status, request_date DESC;
```

CakePHP:

```
'order' => array('request_status, request_date DESC');
```

The DESC keyword applies only to the column name immediately preceding it (request_date); it does not affect the request_status column sort order yet will group them. In other words, above sql query will group request_status fields ordered by their request_date fields.

Another useful link for paginator sorting it's [this one.](http://abcoder.com/php/cakephp/cakephp-advanced-pagination-sort-by-derived-field)